# JUnit Report single page XSLT for email

Tags: xslt, email, junit

I have a Junit process that runs a bunch of data integrity tests every night, and I would like to have it email the results in a nicely formatted HTML email.  The issue is the HTML formatter built into JUnit uses frames and an external stylesheet so it is not appropriate for email.  The plain formatter has the results buried in the midst of a bunch of otherwise worthless data.

I thought it would be simple to find a XSLT stylesheet that formatted the XML output into an email-friendly format, but after a couple hours of googling, I have not been able to find one.  If any of you have a email-friendly Junit formatter, I'd be eternally grateful.

Comment: @Dimitre: Besides JUnit default stylesheet use some extension elements, this is an XSLT question. You could say it's a very specific one like... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/299235/convert-xhtml-to-word-ml as example. If Jhon P post some input sample for JUnit XML output, maybe someone would use a lot of free time to write some stylesheet...

Comment: @Alejandro: I retagged it, because I didn't want to vote to close it. As of now this question is quite incomplete and thus isn't a real question. Any question in this tag that lacks either or both source XML document and/or desired result is incomplete.

Comment: @Dimitre: I completely agree with you: this is a question that has hardly answer.

Comment: @Dimitre:  I found an option on the junitreport task that will compile the test results into a single html file using junit-noframes.xsl.  The problem is it sticks all the <style> information up in a <head> tag, which prevents most HTML email readers from properly displaying it.  Since it seems to be a common problem, I was hoping someone had already hacked that XSL file to produce something more email friendly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junitreport.html

> Ant assumes the following concerning
>   the `frames` and `noframes` formats :
>
> The `frames` format uses a stylesheet
>   which is generating output only by
>   redirecting.
>
> The `noframes` format does not use
>   redirecting and generates one file
>   called `junit-noframes.html`.
>
> Custom versions of `junit-frames.xsl` or
>   `junit-noframes.xsl` must adhere to the
>   above conventions.

**Edit**: The only web aviable source in [here](http://dev.eclipse.org/viewsvn/index.cgi/org.apache.ant/etc/junit-noframes.xsl?view=co&content-type=text%2Fplain)

Comment: The noframes option is close to what I'm looking for, but since it still sticks all the style information up in the <head> tag, most web email clients ignore it and display the results unstyled.  I'll use the junit-noframes.xsl as a starting point then and just build it custom.

Comment: @John P: Good practice (CSS vs inline @style) looks like it makes your task harder. But even M$ Outl**k can handle this HTML format...

Answer (score 0):

Use the one that Ant's `<junitreport>` to create the HTML report and email that.